# Check if file is still opened in Android

Tags: java, android, file

I use a 3rd party library which manipulates with some file (it gets this file as path string). Then I tell this library to release all resources, delete created file and overwrite it. The problem is that I see the old data which has been deleted and ovewritten! The restart of application resolves this issue.

It looks like the resources has not released properly and this library still keep this file. I'd like to somehow (maybe in debug) get the list of files which my app has currently opened and see if this file still opened but I don't know how to do it. Or maybe there is a way to tell Android OS to force close the file. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Had the Android Java SDK been updated to use and implement java.nio.file, you could have used a [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html). Alas, it looks like this is not the case even though Java 7 is several years old now. Maybe an Android specific API can provide the same functionality?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html does the same as WatchService does but I need to check it first.

Comment: If you get shell as the app with run-as you can look in its /proc/###/fd directory with `ls -l`.

Comment: @ChrisStratton lsof command has shown me that the file is still opened in my app. Is there a way force close it?

Comment: Code within (your part of) the application's process could call close() on the file descriptor that you can see.   However, what happens when attempting to use a closed file descriptor is undefined, so its probably not a good idea.

Comment: @ChrisStratton anyway I'd like to try. Do you know how to get file descriptor of opened file. I have only file name as input to the lib.

Comment: Have your program look in /proc/self/fd and find the number sym linked to the filename.  That number is a file descriptor.